# Oracle execute dynamic sql select script and return tabular data

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to execute dynamic sql select statement and return the result back to C# ExecuteReader.

I can retrieve the result in sql server using following sql code.

```
Create Table TestCustomer(ID Varchar(50), CustomerName Varchar(100));

Insert Into TestCustomer (ID, CustomerName) Values ('1', 'One');
Insert Into TestCustomer (ID, CustomerName) Values ('2', 'Two');
Insert Into TestCustomer (ID, CustomerName) Values ('3', 'Three');

DECLARE @SQLScript VARCHAR(MAX), @CustomerName VARCHAR(100);

SET @CustomerName = 'Two';
SET @SQLScript = 'select * from TestCustomer where CustomerName = '''+ @CustomerName +''' ';
EXEC(@SQLScript);
```

[image]

But when I try to retrieve the result on oracle server using following oracle sql code, I don't see table result is coming out like sql server does.

```
DECLARE 
SQLScript VARCHAR2(4000);
CustomerName VARCHAR2(20) := 'Two';
BEGIN
SQLScript := 'select * from TestCustomer where CustomerName = :CustomerName';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLScript USING CustomerName;
END;
```

[image]

How to return the table result once the dynamic sql script is executed, so that c# can get the table result?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your problem involves C#

Comment: @Crowcoder, If oracle can return the result, C# will be fine.

Comment: Right, so it should not be tagged with c#.

Comment: @Crowcoder, removed. Thanks

Comment: Please try to use cursor instead of execute immediate, https://community.oracle.com/thread/702648

Comment: @Govind, I am also considering the performance and memory usage. But thanks for your advise, I am considering.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: SQL server stored procedures can easily return data sets (the way you wrote)  but this won't work with Oracle. To get data from .net you can use ODP.net and create a function that returns a ref cursor: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featRefCursor.htm

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, you have to return the result into something. For example, into a local variable as this example shows:

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table testcustomer as
  2    select 1 id, 'One' customername from dual union all
  3    select 2   , 'Two'              from dual;

Table created.
```

PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    sqlscript      varchar2(4000);
  3    l_customername testcustomer.customername%type := 'Two';
  4    retval         testcustomer.id%type;
  5  begin
  6    sqlscript := 'select id from testcustomer ' ||
  7                 'where customername = :1';
  8    execute immediate sqlscript into retval using l_customername;
  9
 10    -- retval now contains the ID returned by that SELECT statement
 11    dbms_output.put_line('ID = ' || retval);
 12  end;
 13  /
ID = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

However, if you want to actually *return* that value so that it could be used elsewhere, consider using a *function*. Slightly adjusted, code looks like this:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (par_customername in testcustomer.customername%type)
  3    return testcustomer.id%type
  4  is
  5    sqlscript      varchar2(4000);
  6    retval         testcustomer.id%type;
  7  begin
  8    sqlscript := 'select id from testcustomer ' ||
  9                 'where customername = :1';
 10    execute immediate sqlscript into retval using par_customername;
 11
 12    -- retval now contains the ID returned by that SELECT statement
 13    return retval;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test('One') from dual;

F_TEST('ONE')
-------------
            1

SQL>
```

Of course, you can return various things; I returned a scalar value. You can return a refcursor, an array, ... it depends on what you need.

See if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 12c or higher you can use [`dbms_sql.return_result`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS73893) to sort of replicate what you can do with SQL Server:

```
DECLARE 
  SQLScript VARCHAR2(4000);
  CustomerName VARCHAR2(20) := 'Two';
  MyCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SQLScript := 'select * from TestCustomer where CustomerName = :CustomerName';
  OPEN MyCursor FOR SQLScript USING CustomerName;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(MyCursor);
END;
/
```

Read more in [the 12cR1 'what's new' section](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-E1CD6E03-2C47-47F0-997A-DA7327739F0B) and [PL/SQL language guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#GUID-8CFE5AA9-0BBD-417B-A7EE-6F05AF49001B).

> As of Oracle Database 12c, a PL/SQL stored subprogram can return query results to its client implicitly, using the PL/SQL package DBMS_SQL instead of OUT REF CURSOR parameters. This technique makes it easy to migrate applications that rely on the implicit return of query results from stored subprograms from third-party databases to Oracle Database.

---

Incidentally, with the code you had:

```
SQLScript := 'select * from TestCustomer where CustomerName = :CustomerName';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLScript USING CustomerName;
```

Oracle won't complain but the query is not actually executed at all; [see this note](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8__GUID-03324D0E-5267-42B9-98BE-8325F9213352).